# Prove that the following sequences of functions converges to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Let$\ f_n (x)=n^2x(1-x)^n$ I need to prove that$\ f_n→0$ in the interval$\ [0,1]$.

---

Let$\ f_n(x) = nx^n$ prove that$\ f_n→0$ in the interval$\ [0,1)$.

For both of these sequences I tried the following:

By taking the function$\ f(x)=0$ we can see that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x) = 0$$

for both of the sequences, but I don't know if this is the correct way of solving both problems and I have my doubts if this even means that$\ f_n→0$, I'm thinking that what I did before actually implies that$\ f_n→f$.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "By taking the function $f(x) = 0$ we can see that..." What do you mean by this? The result $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = 0$ is precisely what you need to prove. You can't just say "we can see that..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing for
this type of problem
is to look at the derivative
to see how the functions behave.

If
$f_n(x)
=n^2x(1-x)^n
$,
then
$f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$.

Also,

$f_n'(x)
=n^2((1-x)^n-xn(1-x)^{n-1})
=n^2(1-x)^{n-1}(1-x-xn)\\
=n^2(1-x)^{n-1}(1-x(n+1))
$

so
$f_n'(x) = 0$
at
$x_n = \frac1{n+1}$.

At this point,
$f_n(x_n)
=n^2\frac1{n+1}(1-\frac1{n+1})^n
\sim n/e
$
since,
as $n \to \infty$,
$\frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$
and
$(1-1/n)^n \to 1/e$.

Therefore
$f_n$ can be
arbitrarily large
for large enough $n$
and does not
uniformly
converge to zero.

However,
for any given
$x \in (0,1)$,

$\begin{array}\\
n^2(1-x)^n
&=\exp(2\ln(n)+n\ln(1-x))\\
&=\exp(2\ln(n)-n(x+x^2/2+...))\\
&\lt\exp(2\ln(n)-nx))\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{since }2\ln(n)-nx \to -\infty \\
\end{array}
$

since
$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0$
as $n \to \infty$.
Therefore
$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = 0$.

if $n^2$ is replaced by $n$,
then the max value
is about $1/e$,
so $f_n$
again
does not converge uniformly
to z

However,
if the $n^2$
is replaced by a constant
(usually $1$),
then the max value is
about $1/(ne)$
so the sequence uniformly
converges to zero.

Answer (score 1):

One has $f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$, and if $0<x< 1$ is **fixed**, then $0<1-x<1$ and hence, for any fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$ (not only $2$ as in your example)
$$
(1) \qquad n^k(1-x)^n \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty,
$$
and hence $f_n(x) \to 0$.

To see $(1)$, one can (for instance) consider the logarithm of the sequence, namely
$$
\log n^k(1-x)^n = k \log n + n \log (1-x) \to -\infty,
$$
where the latter is due to the fact that the coefficient of $n$ is a fixed strictly negative number, and $n$ grows much faster than the logarithmic function.

The convergence, however, is not uniform, as was pointed in the answer
by @martycohen: the maximum of $f_n$ is at $\frac{1}{n+1}$ where the function stays away from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, we have $f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$, so certainly the sequence converges to zero at $x=0$ and $x=1$. For $0<x<1$, observe that
$$\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)} = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}(1-x),$$
so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)} = 1-x$$
Since $0 < 1-x < 1$, the ratio test implies that the **series** $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges, and therefore the **sequence** $f_n(x)$ must converge to zero.

You can prove the second one quite similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x)=nx^2(1-x)^n$, $x \in [0,1].$

1) $f_n(x)=0$ for $x=0$ or $x=1$.

2) Let $x \in (0,1)$.

Set $y:=1-x$ , where $0<y<1$.

$y^n= \dfrac {1}{z^n}$, where $z: =1/y >1$.

Write $z=1+t$, where $t >0$.

Then:

$f_n(x)=n^2x \dfrac{1}{(1+t)^n} \lt $

$n^2x \dfrac{1}{1+..n(n-1)(n-2)t^3/3!+..}$

$\lt n^2x\dfrac{3!}{(n-3)^3t^3}$.

Hence:

$0<f_n(x)< \dfrac{xn^2}{n^3(1-3/n)^3t^3}$.

Let  $n>6$ then $(1-3/n) >1/2$:

$0<f_n(x) < \dfrac{2^3x}{nt^3}=(\dfrac{2^3x}{t^3})\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Squeeze!